# jquery.reel.min.js 1.3.0. not working with jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Tags: jquery, compatibility, 360-degrees

I've got a problem with the reel plugin for showing a 
360 degree image slider (http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel).

On our website it is obligatory to use jquery 2.1.4.

If both of them are run togheter, the Plugin does not work. Firefox 47 console says:

```
    18:54:37.105 TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a
    s() jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
    .each() jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
    cc() jquery.reel-min.js:14
    k.reel.scan/</<() jquery.reel-min.js:16
   .each() jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
   n.prototype.each() jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
   k.reel.scan/<() jquery.reel-min.js:16
   .each() jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
   n.prototype.each() jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
   k.reel.scan() jquery.reel-min.js:16
   n.Callbacks/j() jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
   n.Callbacks/k.fireWith() jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
   .ready() jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
I() jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
1 jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:3991
```

With jquery.1.9.1  the 360 degree Slider plugin  will work fine, but not with a high ammount of not working other scripted parts on the page, so this is unfortunately no solution for the Problem.

Many thanks in advance! Hope you can help me!

Comment: Try using the non minified versions to get more meaningful errors when developing. Switch to minified before releasing to production.

Comment: Now it says: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
jquery-2.1.4.js
Line 539 Column 6 TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
var length = "length" in obj && obj.length,

Comment: Even if i  just leave the two relevant  scripts in the template document  and delete the rest, the error above remains the same.